# MVC5 redirect to internal url

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to link to an internal Url in mvc5?
I get the url like so: `Source = Request.RawUrl`
this returns: `"/Clients/AddNote"` 
but it can also have parameters: `"/Clients/AddNote/12?items=10"`

This is the code that i have so far:

```
string[] url = Source.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string Controller = url[0];
string Action = url[1];
try{                    
    string id = url[2];
    return RedirectToAction(Action, Controller, new { id = id});
   }
catch{}

return RedirectToAction(Action, Controller);
```

this works good when there is only an ID ad parameter but this code does not handle the named parameters like: `?items=10`

is there a way that i can just say: `return RedirectToAction("/Clients/AddNote/12?items=10");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use: `Request.AbsoluteUri` ?

Comment: this returns the whole url, `"http://www.contoso.com/contracts/Edit/12?source=10"` i there a way i can link to that in the controller?

Comment: oh i found it allready and this fixed it, i just replaced all my previous code whith: `return Redirect(Source);` and then used `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`